# Basic Python Functions (Mathematics involved)

Tags: python, function, math

Coder with very basic skills here:

I've just started to get into coding in Python and testing myself on harder types of functions. Any Mathematicians care to help me with this one? I have found a string of questions online I can do except one of the last ones:

[image: function]

I kind of just need an explanation of what sort of formula this is and how it should be laid out so I might be able to define it with

```
def A(S,K):
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? This is very straight forward with if/else checks. The code is *almost* in the function definition.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Python question. More a question on how to solve a mathematical problem programmatically.

Comment: `if s <= k: return k; if k < s < 2 * k: return 2 * k - s; else: return 0` As you can see, converting the function to Python code is pretty straightforward. What are you having trouble with exactly? What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the if S if greater than or equal to K then f(s) =K, if K<S<2k then f(s)= 2K-S and otherwise f(s)=0? I understand this might be basic but I'm starting almost from scratch :/

Comment: Thank you all, I had just never come across a formula laid out like this

Comment: No, the output of the function is exactly as stated in the function definition. Where are you getting the greater-equal from?

Comment: @G.Ben, you're right, but correction 'if **K** if greater than or equal to **S** then f(s) =K'.

Comment: This is a [piecewise defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is pretty basic, it say: The function 'f' for provided argument 'S' returns value 'K' if value 'S' is less or equal then the value 'K', if the value 'S' is greater then the value 'K' AND lower then the value '2*K' - return value '2*K-S', otherwise return 0.

Python:

```
def A(S,K):
    result = 0
    if S <= K:
        result = K
    elif K < S < 2*K:
        result = 2*K-S
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function with something like:

```
def A(S,K):
    if S <= K:
        f = K
    elif K < S and S < 2*K:
        f = 2*K - S
    else:
        f = 0
    return f
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use that you define a function returning the result, one can avoid stacking the branchings as

```
def A(K,S):
    if S<= K:
        return K
    if S>= 2*K:
        return 0
    return 2*K-S
```

Or as a one-liner that also highlights that it is a continuous function

```
A = lambda K,S : max( 0, min( K, 2*K-S) )
```

resp.

```
A = lambda K,S : max( 0, 2*K - max( K, S) )
```